# Flutter : how do i save input from a text field to an int variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

This is my text controller

```
final amountController = TextEditingController();
         @override
      void dispose() {
        amountController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
```

and when i want to add an item to a list a got an iconbutton that shows a dialog box with a text field where im supposed to get inputs.

```
    IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
//                //this is the part where i add a new income to my list
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Add income'),
                          content: TextField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: amountController,
                            onChanged: (s) {
                              int s = int.parse(amountController.text);
                              amount = s;
                              transactions.add(s);
                            },
                          ),
                        ));
              }),
```

the probleme is that i dont know how to save the data here

```
    List<int> transactions = [];
  int amount = 0;
```

Comment: this `transactions.add(s);` saves your value to  the list

Comment: i dont understand why but it doesnt , see i want that everytime i click on the button i want the function to add a new item to the list , but with this code for exemple if i tap '1234' in the text field and try to print the list it gives me [1,12,123,1234]

Comment: every time you type you update the list ` onChanged: (s) {`, try moving this function to your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not write this line `transactions.add(s);` in onChanged method, because in this way in each number you enter you add a value to the list.
so you have to assign onChanged value to amount value and add a button to your dialog in button's onPressed method add this line `transactions.add(s);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way :

```
    TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  List<int> transactions = [];
  int Total = 0;
  Future<void> _displayTextInputDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    int Amount = 0;
    String valueText = '';
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Add income'),
            content: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  valueText = value;
                });
              },
              controller: _textFieldController,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Amount = int.parse(valueText);
                    transactions.add(Amount);
                    Total = Total + Amount;
                    print(Amount);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

and i just called the function within a flatbutton